# facebook share on page load using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When using below code share on Facebook but `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#_=_` does nothing return.

```
<?php
    $social_link = "https://www.google.co.in";
    $sharelink = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=".urlencode($social_link)."&t=&s=100";
    $strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    echo "<script>var win = window.open('$sharelink', '_self', '$strWindowFeatures');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to echo this? At what point in the page? within `script` tags? Open your browser console and check for errors.

Comment: @Cerbrus why have you added `script` tags to the edit of the source code? The op did not have them in the original php provided. Changes like this could be the very reason why the javascript isn't functioning as intended...

Comment: Eh, I didn't manually add those.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well it's showing that you have added them when I review the edit history **Edit:** but I have just selected `edit` on the original post and it would appear those script tags were in the original edit but failed to display. Mistake on StackoverFlows code display by the looks of it but I also apologies for not double checking the actual post.

Comment: @NewToJS: Look at the markdown diff. I only added spaces. The script tags weren't rendered with the incorrect code formatting. (Which isn't a bug, it just wasn't formatted correctly)

Comment: why would you want to do this? popups should only open on user interaction, usually browsers block those kind ot things anyway. and why would you want access to a return value?

Answer (score 0):

You can create share button using the given tag and add given script in your script section

```
<a onclick="shareinsocialmedia('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $ShareUrl;?>&title=<?php echo $Title;?>')" href=""> <img src="images/facebook.gif" title="share in facebook"> </a>

<script type="text/javascript" async >
    function shareinsocialmedia(url){
    window.open(url,'sharein','toolbar=0,status=0,width=648,height=395');
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I want to open in page not in popup.

Comment: I hope you can open the the same in page also